Keras CV model yolov8 trained on custom dataset problem when exporting model to tflite
I'm training to export a keras-cv object detector based on yolo and pretrained on coco dataset:
`backbone = keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Backbone.from_preset(
           BACKBONE  # yolov8 small backbone with coco weights
           )`

my idea was to export the model (I named yolo_v8_s_mydata) first as a savedmodel format to then convert it to .tflile. Here is the thing, once I trained the model on my custom dataset, I tried to save it with:
`!mkdir -p yolo_v8_s_custom_mdl
yolo_v8_s_mydata.save('yolo_v8_s_custom_mdl/my_model')`

I got the following:
`ValueError: Invalid filepath extension for saving. Please add either a `.keras` extension for the native Keras format (recommended) or a `.h5` extension. Use `model.export(filepath)` if you want to export a SavedModel for use with TFLite/TFServing/etc. Received: filepath=yolo_v8_s_arandanos_mdl/my_model.`

Well, following the suggestion of using the method model.export I did it ,but it changes the information about the input and output formats of the model, it saves the model and then I convert it to tflite but the input and outupt shapes ar not coherent, first, when executing the export method it displays the following:
`Saved artifact at 'yolo_v8_s_arandanos_mdl/my_model'. The following endpoints are available:

* Endpoint 'serve'
  args_0 (POSITIONAL_ONLY): TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='keras_tensor_122')
Output Type:
  Dict[['boxes', TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 64), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)], ['classes', TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)]]
Captures:
  136080137385616: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080137372064: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080137376816: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080137387376: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080137377168: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080194141728: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080194138032: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080194131872: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080194126944: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080194126592: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080195802864: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
  136080138224736: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.resource, name=None)
.... etc`

When I run predictions only with the trained model and .predict there is no problems.
When I load the tflite model and inspect the input and outputs I have the following:
`== Input details ==
name: serving_default_keras_tensor_122:0
shape: [1 1 1 3]
type: <class 'numpy.float32'>
[{'name': 'serving_default_keras_tensor_122:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([1, 1, 1, 3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, -1, -1,  3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

== Output details ==
name: StatefulPartitionedCall_1:0
shape: [ 1  1 64]
type: <class 'numpy.float32'>
[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall_1:0', 'index': 478, 'shape': array([ 1,  1, 64], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, -1, 64], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall_1:1', 'index': 477, 'shape': array([1, 1, 3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, -1,  3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]`

even when converting to tflite I had issues, I was getting this:
`ConverterError: Could not translate MLIR to FlatBuffer.<unknown>:0: error: loc(callsite(callsite(fused["Conv2D:", "yolov8_detector_1/pa_fpn_p4p5_pre_conv_1/convolution@__inference___call___119861"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___121144"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): 'tf.Conv2D' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"]): called from
<unknown>:0: note: loc(callsite(callsite(fused["Conv2D:", "yolov8_detector_1/pa_fpn_p4p5_pre_conv_1/convolution@__inference___call___119861"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___121144"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
<unknown>:0: error: loc(callsite(callsite(fused["Conv2D:", "yolov8_detector_1/pa_fpn_p3p4p5_pre_conv_1/convolution@__inference___call___119861"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___121144"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): 'tf.Conv2D' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"]): called from
<unknown>:0: note: loc(callsite(callsite(fused["Conv2D:", "yolov8_detector_1/pa_fpn_p3p4p5_pre_conv_1/convolution@__inference___call___119861"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___121144"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': 
Some ops are not supported by the native TFLite runtime, you can enable TF kernels fallback using TF Select. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select 
TF Select ops: Conv2D
Details:
    tf.Conv2D(tensor<?x?x?x?xf32>, tensor<1x1x384x128xf32>) -> (tensor<?x?x?x128xf32>) : {data_format = "NHWC", dilations = [1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings = [], padding = "VALID", strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu = true}
    tf.Conv2D(tensor<?x?x?x?xf32>, tensor<1x1x768x256xf32>) -> (tensor<?x?x?x256xf32>) : {data_format = "NHWC", dilations = [1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings = [], padding = "VALID", strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu = true}`


then suggested by the AI from colab I added these lines and it somehow solved it before applying the .convert() method (at least I was able to have a tflite model):
`converter_detector.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # Enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS  # Enable TensorFlow ops.
]`

Have someone faced this issue before? I'm running the code on google colab, I followed the example from object detection with keras-cv.
Thanks
I'm trying to follow  some examples from keras-cv and reading the documentation but there is no information about how to export and convert this keras-cv yolov8 model (up to what I've seen) to tflite.
